# Opening a File - C programming

Tags: c

I need help understanding why this code won't open the file i'm asking it to open.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int main(){

    FILE *pFile;

    pFile = fopen("C:\Users\Wilmer\Desktop\abc.txt", "w");

    if (pFile != NULL){
    printf("Hello");

    fclose(pFile);

    }else{
    printf("File does not exist.");

    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fopen returns null - Perror prints Invalid argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182178/fopen-returns-null-perror-prints-invalid-argument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `\` with double slash `\\`:

```
pFile = fopen("C:\\Users\\Wilmer\\Desktop\\abc.txt", "w");
```

A single slash makes them interpret as escape sequences. Escaping the single slash will do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash (`\`) characters:

```
pFile = fopen("C:\\Users\\Wilmer\\Desktop\\abc.txt", "w");
```

Or use slash (`/`):

```
pFile = fopen("C:/Users/Wilmer/Desktop/abc.txt", "w");
```